# how to apply TDD Test to Struts2 action classes

Tags: java, spring, struts2, junit, tdd

I have an application that uses Spring and Struts2, and I want to add TDD Test to the actions classes using Junit. so using the guide on [Struts Junit plugin Page](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/struts-2-junit-plugin-tutorial.html) i build the following classes:

Action Class:

```
package articulos.aumentoprecio.controlador;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import articulos.aumentoprecio.transporte.AumentoPrecioPojo;

public class MostrarAumentoPrecioAction extends ActionSupport {
    private AumentoPrecioPojo aumentoPrecio = new AumentoPrecioPojo();

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {

        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public AumentoPrecioPojo getAumentoPrecio() {
        return aumentoPrecio;
    }

    public void setAumentoPrecio(AumentoPrecioPojo aumentoPrecio) {
        this.aumentoPrecio = aumentoPrecio;
    }    
}
```

And the Junit test case:

```
package articulos.aumentoprecio.controlador;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionProxy;
import org.apache.struts2.StrutsJUnit4TestCase;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath*:applicationContext.xml"}) 
public class MostrarAumentoPrecioActionTest extends StrutsJUnit4TestCase {

    public MostrarAumentoPrecioActionTest() {
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
    }

    @Test
    public void testExecute() throws Exception {
        ActionProxy proxy = getActionProxy("/MostrarMenu.action");
        MostrarAumentoPrecioAction controlador = (MostrarAumentoPrecioAction) proxy.getAction();
        String result = proxy.execute();

        assertEquals("El submodulo AumentoPrecio no esta integrado", "success", result);
    }
}
```

However when executing the TDD shows me NullPointerException in method getActionProxy.

the stacktrace show in the output window is:

```
Testcase: testExecute(articulos.aumentoprecio.controlador.MostrarAumentoPrecioActionTest):  Caused an ERROR
null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.struts2.StrutsJUnit4TestCase.getActionProxy(StrutsJUnit4TestCase.java:142)
Test articulos.aumentoprecio.controlador.MostrarAumentoPrecioActionTest FAILED
```

Is there any extra configuration that is not in the struts guide?

Comment: Sorry, this may be clear to others, but to me TDD refers to either Test Driven Development, Top Down Design or Technical Design Document.  None of these seem to fit your question, can you clarify?

Comment: sorry, is about how to apply Test Driven Development Test to Struts2 classes

Comment: Never done this before - but won't the test class need to know something about your struts configuration? You're telling it where the spring config is, but don't mention struts config at all. Surely it'll need that so it can map the /MostrarMenu.action to an action class?

Comment: Show the full stacktrace.

Comment: i append it to the question, i dont know why only show me a few lines of the stacktrace

Comment: If you are using spring then extend struts spring test case.

Comment: i already tried that but still not work

Comment: It looks like you can test this class without a Spring context, so I would just use a plain JUnit4 test